# Yosemite: is there a way to put back Spotlight under the magnifying glass?

Tags: macos, spotlight, menu-bar

I would like to get the Spotlight prompt under the magnifying glass positioned in the top right of the screen under the menu bar. Yosemite shows it in the middle of the screen.

Is this configurable or hackable?

Comment: maybe you should have a look and try [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) instead. Do way more things that spotlight and you can move the bar wherever you want.

Comment: It now works with El Capitan!